# Get resource(jar) path in java

Tags: java, window, classpath, executable-jar

I have a class XYZ in application that is executed as jar in any directory. I want to find the current directory path in which jar is executing for this I have used following code.

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

I write this code in public constructor of XYZ class but it is not working though I am using it since long time it works fine, but now it is not returning the current directory path.

please mark and suggest what is going wrong in this.

Comment: Does the class of current instance (`this`) come from the jar file you try to locate? Because this only works if it does.

Comment: @icza yes this clas is zipped in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your statement within "this" - it means that you are trying to locate current instance of the class but you need to find the class itself.
In your case you can use this:

> String path = XYZ.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
>
> String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

It will give you the path you are looking for and will solve issues with whitespaces and special characters inside this path.

In case you are doing this for Linux it might be useful to use:

> URLDecoder.decode(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath(‌​), "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

```
 return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

OR

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().toURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...but now it is not returning the current directory path.

It shouldn't return the current directory path. It should return the path of the jar file the class is coming from, or the root folder where the class files are loaded from (if not packed in a jar). It might and it might not be the current folder.

Calling

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

will try to locate the path the class of the current instance (`this`) is coming from.

Make sure that the `Class` you start from is part of the jar file. E.g. do not use `this` but use an explicit class which you're sure is from the jar file, e.g.

```
SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Also note that this won't work if you start the application from your IDE in which case the result would be the `bin` folder (the root folder of compiled class files).

Comment: I have used XYZ.this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() but it is still not working. current directory means the directoy path where jar is currently placed.

Comment: Can you post the actual jar path and the path you're getting?

Comment: all suggestions are fine they are working fine from the code when i debug it shows the root directory path but when i create the executable jar and placed it some where it returns "./". could not understand why. I am decoding it as some person suggesting but point is i am not getting correct executable jar path.

Comment: any comment on this please

Comment: It works for me. There must be something you're not telling us. You're case is not reproducible with the known information.

Comment: String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()  this is line that i have written in the constructor of XYZ. what i have newly added is, i am reading a resource file before this, i dont think this is related to this. i am suprise, apart from that please ask what else you want to know.